# Where clause to filter timestamp data by using only date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a `where` clause to extract data but into database I have datetime stamp and I want to extract data by using only date information.

```
select *
from invoice
where invoice_date = '2019-06-24'
```

But I have into database invoice_date = 2019-06-24 04:30:00.000

Answer (score 2):

Cast it to date:

```
select *
from invoice
where CAST(invoice_date as DATE) = '2019-06-24'
```

Comment: One issue with this solution is that it will not use an index on the date column unless the index was built on the calculation of casted value, which is very unlikely.

Comment: actually, I did cast as well but did not work in my first attempt but now it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That isn't quite true, @RacilHilan. `CAST(... AS date)` and `CONVERT(date,..)` *are* SARGable (but that doesn't mean you should do it). There is a post about it on DBA, but my GoogleFu is failing me.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, my comment was not accurate, but I was just trying to point out an issue without diving too deep in the details as the space for the comments is limited. You're right, they are SARGable and will use the index, but not as efficiently as when using a range. And since using a range is pretty simple, there is no point in paying a performance cost for casting. Apologies for the inaccurate comment.

Comment: [Sargable - but should you use it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: @SMor That's a great explanation and a good follow up in the second answer. I should've included such a link instead of providing a skimmed down inaccurate answer. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use "proper" date logic:

```
SELECT {Column List}
FROM dbo.invoice i
WHERE i.invoice_date >= '2019-06-24'
  AND i.invoice_date < '2019-06-25';
```

If you're using a parameter, then you would use `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT {Column List}
FROM dbo.invoice i
WHERE i.invoice_date >= @DateParam
  AND i.invoice_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateParam);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve what you want. Either cast the timestamp to date, which is very readable, or use a time range.

```
select *
from invoice
where invoice_date >= '2019-06-24' and invoice_date < '2019-06-25';
```

Working with a time range is slightly less readable, but if you have an index on `invoice_date` it can be used, so the query may run faster.